# Preprocess e2e tests' files (ES6 styling) for Protractor using webpack

Tags: reactjs, protractor, ecmascript-6, webpack, e2e-testing

I'm using

1. React: application
2. npm: package manager
3. mocha/chai/sinon: unit test
4. protractor: e2e testing

in my application. The entire application is written with ES6, but the e2e tests are plain javascript. I would like to use ES6 styling for my e2e tests files as well, but the issue that I am facing is to preprocess or compile the ES6 files to plain javascript and then run the protractor agains compiled files. Can anyone please point how to use webpack with babel to convert those ES6 files into plain javascript?

here is my `protractor.conf.js`:

```
/*eslint-disable no-var*/
'use strict';

exports.config = {
  specs: ['../tests/e2e/**/*.js'],
  capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome'
  },
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:3000',
  frameworks: ['mocha', 'chai'],
  onPrepare: function() {
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
  }
};
```

and a simple test:

```
/*eslint-disable no-var*/
'use strict';

var chai = require('chai');
var sinon = require('sinon');
var sinonChai = require('sinon-chai');

var expect = chai.expect;
chai.use(sinonChai);

describe('app login flow', function() {

  var loginUrl, homeUrl;

  it('sets up initial variables', function() {
    browser.get('/teams');
    loginUrl = browser.getCurrentUrl();

    browser.sleep(6000).then(function() {
      homeUrl = browser.getCurrentUrl();
      expect('1').to.equal('1');
    })
  });
});
```

Comment: With _plain javascript_ you mean ES5?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was solved simply by adding `require('babel/register');` at the very top of the `protractor.conf.js` file. for more info check this [issue on github](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/2049)

So the `protractor.conf.js` now looks like this:

```
/*eslint-disable no-var*/
'use strict';

require('babel/register');

exports.config = {
  specs: ['../tests/e2e/**/*.js'],
  capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome'
  },
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:3000',
  frameworks: ['mocha', 'chai'],
  onPrepare: function() {
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
  },

};
```

and the test files now can be written in ES6.

```
/*eslint-disable no-var*/
'use strict';

import chai from 'chai';
import sinon from 'sinon';
import sinonChai from 'sinon-chai';

let expect = chai.expect;
chai.use(sinonChai);

describe('app login flow', () => {
  let loginUrl, homeUrl;
  it('sets up initial variables', () => {
    browser.get('/teams');

    browser.sleep(6000).then(() => {
      expect('1').to.equal('1');
    })
  });
});
```

PS.
a good reference for making protractor to work with ReactJs:
[Testing React apps with Protractor](http://joelotter.com/2015/04/18/protractor-reactjs.html) by [Joel Auterson](http://joelotter.com/)

**UPDATE**

> Just in case anyone reads the link at the bottom of this answer - I wrote that post a while ago, and it's now a little out of date. :) ExpectedConditions is probably what you want! – Joel Auterson

Comment: this set up doesn't give the proper stacktrace line number when an error happens though

Comment: In case anyone else stumbles into this, don't forget to use `require('babel-register');` instead if you grab it separately from NPM depending on how you pull babel into your project.

Comment: Just in case anyone reads the link at the bottom of this answer - I wrote that post a while ago, and it's now a little out of date. :) ExpectedConditions is probably what you want!

Answer (score 4):

For Babel 6 version put following at the top (or in onPrepare) of the protractor.conf.js:

```
require("babel-core/register")({
    presets: [
        "es2015"
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old, but to update it I want to mention that since protractor was written on Node you can now use ES6 with it without any tweaks in conf file, you just need to use Node >= 4. 
However some of the features(let, classes) require strict mode.

For more information about supported ES6 features you can check this page https://nodejs.org/en/docs/es6/